# Get field value from within a Map

Tags: lightning-web-components, map

I have a Map that is returned from apex to my LWC.  Below is the apex:

```
 public static Map<string, opportunity> existingOppCheck(id accountId, id brokerId, date effDate, id ownerId, List<string> allRecTypes){
/////Map<String, Id> recordTypeMap = new Map<String, Id>();
Map<String, opportunity> recordTypeMap = new Map<String, opportunity>();
List<opportunity> existingOppList = [select RecordTypeId, RecordType.Name, Name, LOB__c, CloseDate, owner.name
FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = : accountId and Broker__c = : BrokerId and ownerId = : ownerId 
and CloseDate = : effDate and RecordTypeId in : allRecTypes Order By closedate DESC];
for(opportunity opp: existingOppList){
  /////recordTypeMap.put(opp.RecordType.Name, opp.RecordTypeId); 
  recordTypeMap.put(opp.RecordType.Name, opp); 
}
return recordTypeMap;
```

}

When I get the map back, I use it to check a list to see if opps in the list are already created.  That works file.  But I also want to display a list of the returned opps from recordTypeMap.  I am struggling to figure out how I display that.  I was trying to assign just the values of the map to a list which I would then display but that is not working.  From what I have found, I can't display a map in my lwc so how do I get the values of my map and place them in a list to display?  Here is my method where I am calling the apex.  In my console.log I see an a label and value but can't figure out how to get just the value.  this is what the console.log returns:

```
zz here is the alreadyCreatedRecTypes [{"label":"New Business Health","value":{"RecordTypeId":"012700000001e8YAAQ","Name":"2024 02 / Health / Test Account 33z / cabde / Broker 1","LOB__c":"Health","CloseDate":"2024-02-01","OwnerId":"00570000001kT0AAAU","Id":"0068A00000ERAS5QAP","RecordType":{"Name":"New Business Health","Id":"012700000001e8YAAQ"},"Owner":{"Name":"Chaunte Abdellah","Id":"00570000001kT0AAAU"}}}]
```

Here is the javascript method:

```
Step 2 - get the list of opportunities that are already created (based on account, owner, market and eff date selected)
existingOppCheck({accountId: this.accountId, brokerId: this.selectedBrokerId, effDate: this.selectedEffDate, ownerId: this.selectedOwnerId, 
  allRecTypes: this.clonedFromOppRecTypes})
  
  .then(data => {
    //1. get existing opp record types
  this.alreadyCreatedRecTypes = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({
    label: key, 
    value:data[key]
  }));  
  console.log('zz here is the alreadyCreatedRecTypes ' + JSON.stringify(this.alreadyCreatedRecTypes));
```

Here is the datatable not displaying

```
<lightning-card title="The following Opps have previously been created with the new criteria you selected" icon-name="action:close">        
            <lightning-datatable
                id="nonCloneableList"
                data={alreadyCreatedRecTypes}
                columns={noCloneColumns}
                column-widths-mode=auto
                min-column-width=115
                key-field="Id"
                class="inActiveRecords"
                hide-checkbox-column="true"
            >                     
            </lightning-datatable> 
        </lightning-card>
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
value:data[key]
```

Can be:

```
value:Object.entries(data[key]).map(([field,value])=>({field,value}))
```

This changes the data into an array of field/value objects. You can iterate over this array to show the values.

Comment: Thank you!  When I make that change and run the process get an error, " Value not Defined"

Comment: @Frank That's what I get for trying to write code on my phone. Try the latest edit.